# Localstorage not working in app initialization

Tags: angularjs, cordova, local-storage

I have code below

```
angular
.module('core')
.factory('jsonstorage',function($rootScope,$http,$localStorage){

     return {
        set: function(entidy, value) {
           $rootScope.$storage = $localStorage;
            $rootScope.$storage[entidy] = value;

        },
        get: function(entidy) {
          if (typeof $rootScope.$storage != 'undefined') {
            return $rootScope.$storage[entidy];
          }
        }
    } 


});
```

Controller

```
angular
.module('core')
.controller('HomeController', function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$localStorage,jsonstorage) {
  var url = "http://test.com/?feed=xml";
  $http.get(
  url,
  {transformResponse:function(data) {
  // convert the data to JSON and provide
  // it to the success function below
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
    return json;
  }
  }).
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
     jsonstorage.set('eventlist', data.feed.events.event);
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
      console.error('Error fetching feed:', data);
  }); 

$scope.feed.items =  $rootScope.storage['eventlist']


console.log(jsonstorage.get('eventlist'))

console.log($scope.storage['eventlist']);
});
```

Problem:

On installing app in android device, storage return undefined value. but when i  reload the app through chrome://inspect/#devices all data feed loads back.

i dont have problem with chrome browser in desktop.

It happens all the time when i delete app and reintialize it in device

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: that ajax call is async. So, set method would have been applied by the time you call the get method .

Comment: Do you have any idea how to fix it thanks

Comment: call get method only when set method is already called in success... May be You can call get method in success itself. Try remodeling the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everytime you delete your app, local storage is deleted with it. There is no way to persist data between app deletions.

Also, the AJAX call you are making is an asynchronous call, you have to initialise your `$scope.feeds.items` in .success() method not outside that as below:

```
angular.module('core')controller('HomeController',
   function($scope,$http,$rootScope,$localStorage,jsonstorage) {
     var url = "http://test.com/?feed=xml";
     $http.get(url, {transformResponse:function(data) {
      var x2js = new X2JS();
      var json = x2js.xml_str2json( data );
      return json;
   }
 }).
 success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
   jsonstorage.set('eventlist', data.feed.events.event);
   $scope.feed.items =  $rootScope.storage['eventlist'];
   console.log(jsonstorage.get('eventlist'))
   console.log($scope.storage['eventlist']);
 }).
 error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  console.error('Error fetching feed:', data);
 }); 
 });
```

Also, your code is working when you refresh your page , becaue by that time, the response of your first AJAX call is returned  and thus your `$scope.feeds.items` is initialised.